# Navigate to UserControl after LoginVerification in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, expression-blend

I have got a Login UserControl and a ModuleHomeScreen UserControl.

My Login UserControl has got a Username and Password TextBox and a LoginButton.
When user clicks on LoginButton his credentials are verified from database; and then he has to be navigated to ModuleHomeScreen UserControl.

The UserCredentials Verification is working perfectly.
MainWindow has got a NavigationFrame where I am switching the UserControl.

Now my problem is:
Without filling up the user credentials, when a user clicks on login button he is still navigated to the Dashboard UserControl.
Even there is some problem with the Navigation code !

How do I first verify the Login Credentials and if it is successful then Navigate to different UserControl ?

Here is my Code attached:

Login.xaml

```
    public void loginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (LoginUserName.Text != "" && LoginPassword.Password != "")
        {
            NpgsqlConnection con = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=localhost;Port=1234;UserID=postgres;Password=root;Database=postgres");
            con.Open();
            String username = LoginUserName.Text.Trim();
            String encPassword = TripleDESCrypto.Encrypt(LoginPassword.Password.Trim(),true);
            String query = "SELECT * FROM login where username= '" + username + "' and password = '" + encPassword + "';";
            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(query, con);
            NpgsqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.Read())
            {
               // ServiceContainer.GetService<INavigationService>().Navigate("ModuleHomeScreen", null, this);
                LoginErrorMessage.Text = "Login Successfull";
                MainWindow appWindow = new MainWindow();
                ModuleHomeScreen appScreen = new ModuleHomeScreen();
                appWindow.MainWindowNavigationFrame.Navigate(appScreen,null);
            }
            else
            {
                LoginErrorMessage.Text = "Invalid Login Credentials.";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            LoginErrorMessage.Text = "Please enter all fields !";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    public void loginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(LoginUserName.Text))
        {
            ////Password could be empty for some user's
            if (LoginPassword.Password == null)
                LoginPassword.Password = string.Empty;

            NpgsqlConnection con = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=localhost;Port=1234;UserID=postgres;Password=root;Database=postgres");
            con.Open();
            String username = LoginUserName.Text.Trim();
            String encPassword = TripleDESCrypto.Encrypt(LoginPassword.Password.Trim(), true);
            String query = "SELECT count(*) FROM login where username= '" + username + "' and password = '" + encPassword + "';";
            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(query, con);
            int? dr = cmd.ExecuteScalar() as int?;
            if (dr.HasValue && dr.Value > 0)
            {
                // ServiceContainer.GetService<INavigationService>().Navigate("ModuleHomeScreen", null, this);
                LoginErrorMessage.Text = "Login Successfull";
                MainWindow appWindow = new MainWindow();
                ModuleHomeScreen appScreen = new ModuleHomeScreen();
                appWindow.MainWindowNavigationFrame.Navigate(appScreen, null);
            }
            else
            {
                LoginErrorMessage.Text = "Invalid Login Credentials.";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            LoginErrorMessage.Text = "Please enter user name !";
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried the above code.
After clicking the Login Button, the UserControl is not navigating to different view (ModuleHomeScreen UserControl).
Even after entering proper user credentials its displaying "Invalid login credentials."

Comment: Password which is sent is Encrypted using TripleDESCryptographic Method.

Navigation to different View is also not working.

Comment: The Previous Code which I uploaded seems to be working fine.

The user credentials are getting verified and I am able to see Login Successfull Message.
But after that I am not able to navigate to ModuleHomeScreen View ..